# Solving integrals through “integral systems.”

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Hello fellow MSE users I have recently evaluated two integrals simultaneously and was wondering if any of you had other examples of solving integrals this way, specifically non-elementary definite integrals please! Here is my work as to illustrate the technique I am talking about.

Consider the following two integrals:

$$I:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\sin(x))\,dx$$

$$J:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\cos(x))\,dx$$

So it follows that

$$I+J=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x))\,dx$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\sin(2x))\,dx$$

Let $$2x\longrightarrow{x}$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(\sin(x))\,dx$$

The integral left is one of Euler’s famous integrals which has a well known value. So implementing this and doing the arithmetic it follows that:

$$I+J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$

Then we consider

$$I-J=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log(\tan(x))\,dx$$

Let $$\tan(x)\longrightarrow{x}$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$$

Using a series expansion it is elementary to prove that

$$I-J=-G$$

Where G is Catalan’s constant

So we have the following 2x2 linear system, namely:

$$I+J=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$
$$I-J=-G$$

Solving it yields:

$$I=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}G$$

$$J= -\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac{1}{2}G$$

Comment: I remember watching [this video](https://youtu.be/X9ZjK1wiSfo) in my junior year of university. The YouTuber makes a lot of jokes and isn't family-friendly at times, but he does something similar to what you did in this post so I think it's worth sharing.